# How do I force an error from my code.js function?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Basically I have a "withFailureHandler" and if I WANT to trigger this coming back from my code.gs function how do I do that?

Comment: `throw` statement

Comment: Here's a link [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Comment: To be more specific, the failure handler is only called for **unhandled** server-side exceptions. If you `throw` within a `try { ... }` block and have a `catch` or suitable `finally` clause, then your failure handler won't get called. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#failure_handlers

Answer (score 3):

Use the `throw` statement to trigger an error:

```js
try {
    throw "error message";
}
catch (e) {
    // e is set to "error message" here
}
```